# RoR: How to create a dynamic text image with a specific font

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick

What I am looking for is some sample code, preferably Ruby on Rails, on how to dynamically create an image containing text in a specific font.

Basically I want to create a URL like this:

```
/api/text_as_image?font=futura&text=foo
```

And have it return an image containing the text "foo" in the font "futura". I know this can be done with ImageMagick, just can't seem to figure it out. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Check out the [magick_title](http://github.com/citrus/magick_title) gem:

Here's the basic usage:

```
# this could come from your form
params[:magick_title] = { :font_size => 24, :color => '#ff0000' }

# Then in your controller 
MagickTitle.say("Hello!", params[:magick_image]).to_html
```